# Acyclic Graph of Definitions of a Language

Tags: semantics

Given a certain language L, let's define it's language graph G as the graph where nodes correspond to words and a directed edge between node B and node A implies that the word referenced by B belongs to the definition of the word referenced by A.

My question is, can we construct a set of definitions that still reflect the semantic meaning of the words of L while also resulting in G being acyclic? If it is not the case, can we construct an artificial language that follows this property?

An acyclic definition graph would imply the existence of certain words without a definition but such a graph can result in a topological sort of words. Thus an ordered hierarchy for learning the words of the language.

Comment: The [Natural Semantic Metalanguage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_semantic_metalanguage) is one attempt to solve the problem of circular definitions.

Comment: I don't understand the idea of a word "belonging to the definition" of another word. Also, how do we know if a definition "reflects" the meaning of a word?

Comment: @user6726 Let's take for example the oxford's definition of the word "Person" : "A human being regarded as an individual."
Since the word "human" belongs to the definition of the word "person" then there is a directed edge from the node corresponding to "human" to that of "person". A definition reflects the meaning if it succeeds in defining it. I do not know of any formal way of expressing this statement.

Comment: @curiousdannii Thanks ! This is an interesting read.

Comment: In other words, "contains", i.e. that definition of "person" contains the word "human". I would say a definition *states* the meaning of a word α iff it identifies all and only the referents of α. And you want all words to be defined by propositions composed only of other words (non-circularly).

Comment: Sounds like you are describing a dependency tree, but with the edges pointing up the tree toward the root node instead of down it toward the leaves.

Comment: In practice the graph will always have cycles, after all words are defined by the contexts in which they’re used. That said, there are formal approaches that build up acyclic graphs for the interpretation of a given sentence based on ontologies with cycles, but such techniques pertain to pragmatics rather than semantics.

Comment: Similar questions have been asked here before w.r.t. lexicography.